# How to set ufw to allow Remote Desktop Sharing on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: networking, 22.04, firewall, remote-desktop, ufw

I know there is a command such `sudo apt ufw allow <app>` but the problem is I don't know what is the app name.
So if I enable `ufw` I can't connect to my ubuntu device from my mac via RDP, and I can connect to it only if I disable the firewall (ufw).

I tried, checking for the service name from the System Monitor app, but not luck.

Also, googled about this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you believe you need an ufw rule? And it would more likely be based on IP and port. Like so `sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3389 proto tcp`  ip, port, and protocol allowed.

Comment: Because following the Samba server setup guide there is a part that showing it to add samba to the ufw list, so I thought it's the same. Anyway, I will try your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK it's up to application developers whether they provide a UFW application integration profile - a quick search with `apt-file` doesn't appear to show anything for either RDP or VNC from the standard repositories